# create a html file with nested divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an array of objects each of which having the following variables:

```
class nodeProps {
  constructor(id, name, data, parent, children) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

each object will become a div tag in the html file with some divs being the child of another. i am having trouble being able to close the tags when they are being nested within each other.
what i have so far only adds the first child (i would like to add them all) and doesnt close it:

```
function createTag(nodes, node) {
  if (node.children != null) {
    // let kidList = node.children;
    let kids = nodes.filter((x) => node.children.includes(x.id));
    let tag = `<div className={styles.${node.name}}> ${createTag(
      nodes,
      kids[0]
    )}`;

    return tag;
  } else {
    return `<div className={styles.${node.name}}> </div>\n`;
  }
}
```

i have been ignoring indentation as you currently see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version of the function that will correctly create tags for all children and close them properly:

```
function createTag(nodes, node) {
  let tag = `<div className={styles.${node.name}}>`;
  if (node.children != null) {
    let kids = nodes.filter((x) => node.children.includes(x.id));
    for (let i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
      tag += createTag(nodes, kids[i]);
    }
  }
  tag += `</div>\n`;
  return tag;
}
```

This function uses recursion to create tags for all children and their children, and appends them to the parent tag. The parent tag is then closed at the end.

Comment: Did it work? I'm so excited. This was an experiment. I didn't even read your question. I don't understand your question too. I copied your question into AI tool chatgpt (https://chat.openai.com/chat) and it answered me Instantly. I pasted it here. This is awesome.
It might be against the community rules, but I can't help expressing my surprise here.